# Android Dialog box not showing

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, ringtonemanager

I am developing a app for Android. I have a method called ringtone that is called when certain conditions are met. I wanted to create a lound sound and create a dialog box to dismiss the sound. 
My code:

```
    public void ringtone() {
        AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 10, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
            Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            final Ringtone r= RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("We Detected You Were Asleep");
        alertDialog.setMessage("WAKE UP!");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "I am Awake", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    r.stop();
                }
            });

        r.play();
        alertDialog.show();
}
```

When I run my app the ringtone volume changes but the ringtone doesn't play. However when I comment out the dialog box builder the ringtone rings. So my conclusion is that there is something wrong within the dialog box builder that isnt allowing the code to continue.

Answer (score 0):

I have wondered that myself a few times: My dialog was shown on an activity, that was currently off screen.

Solution: You need to create the builder with the context of the activity, the dialog should be displayed with.

I have created the builder with the context of another activity (my shared main activity) and that was wrong.

Now in your case, you might have to create and show a translucent activity, where you display your dialog on. Creating a translucent activity is just a few settings in the manifest file.